# Observable pattern on reactive extension

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I am trying to understand the below code trying to use reactive extensions

```
 IObservable<string> textChangedObservable =
            Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(searchScrip, "TextChanged")
                .Select(evt => ((TextBox) sender).Text);

 textChangedObservable.Subscribe(OnNext, OnCompleted);

private void OnNext(string s)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("OnNext " + s + "\n");
    }

    private void OnCompleted()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("OnCompleted " + "\n");
    }
```

If I enter SEARC in the input box, the output looks

- OnNext SE
- OnNext SEA
- OnNext SEA
- OnNext SEAR
- OnNext SEAR
- OnNext SEAR
- OnNext SEARC
- OnNext SEARC
- OnNext SEARC
- OnNext SEARC

  1. Why is "S" not triggering an OnNext?
  2. Why is OnCompleted never called?
  3. Why is the OnNext called n-1 time on the nth character?

Comment: Not an easy question since the class `XamTextEditor` is not effortlessly available. I suspect it might have something to do with it's implementation of `RoutedPropertyChanged`

Comment: Actually, you need to tell us what XAML elements are `searchScrip` and `sender`.

Comment: Changed the code sample to use wpf text box to keep things simple. But the behavious is still the same as in the questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are subscribing to the observable in your `searchScrip_TextChanged` handler.

This means that the first time that `searchScrip_TextChanged` gets called the `S` has already happened **before** you've wired up the observable. So of course it doesn't fire.

But now that the `S` is hit you have one subscription so when the `E` is typed you get a single `SE`. But since the `searchScrip_TextChanged` handler gets called for the `E` too you now have two subscriptions to your observable.

So when the `A` is typed you get two `SEA` because you have two observables. But again the `searchScrip_TextChanged` is called for the `A` so now you have three observables.

Etc, etc, etc.

Events don't complete automatically. You need to manually dispose of the subscriptions to have them end. This should make sense because that's what you have to do with normal event handlers that you want to stop.

You should create your observable when your form is loaded so that it is created once.

It should look like this:

```
IObservable<string> textChangedObservable =
        Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(searchScrip, "TextChanged")
            .Select(evt => searchScrip.Text);

IDisposable subscription =
    textChangedObservable
        .Subscribe(
            s => Debug.Print("OnNext " + s + "\n"),
            s => Debug.Print("OnCompleted\n"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here really has nothing to do with Rx.

> 1: Why is "S" not triggering an OnNext?

Because the `TextChanged` event you have subscribed to did not fire on the first S.

> 2: Why is OnCompleted never called?

When you wrap a .NET event as an `IObservable<T>`, you never get `OnError` or `OnCompleted` notifications. There is no concept of error or completion with a .NET event.

If there are *two* events, one for values and one for completion, you can combine them like so:

```
var values = Observable.FromEvent(...);
var completion = Observable.FromEvent(...);
var query = values.TakeUntil(completion);
```

Now `query` will yield a proper `OnCompleted` notification.

> 3: Why is the OnNext called n-1 time on the nth character?

Because the `TextChanged` event you have subscribed to fired this way. As was pointed out by @Kari-Antti, this may be a side effect of using a "routed property" event.

Comment: 1. My XAML for searchScript is <igWPF:XamTextEditor Name="searchScrip" TextChanged="searchScrip_TextChanged" /> and when I put a break point, it does get triggered for "S" at the implementation "private void searchScrip_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<string> e)"

Comment: @asb I don't know how to assist you beyond what I've said already. The observable will emit no differently than the underlying event.  It's a very simple mechanism.  So what you're saying, that the observable and the event are not working the same, contradicts what I know to be true.

Comment: @TimothyShields - He's repeated subscribing to the observable - that's why the `OnNext` is being called `n - 1` times.

Comment: @TimothyShields - And the observable hasn't been subscribed to yet when the `S` is typed.

Comment: @Enigmativity I missed the fact that they occurred 0,1,2,... times.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because you have used RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs?

What about if you use PropertyChangedEventHandler?

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                h => yourModel.propertyChanged += h,
                h => yourModel.propertyChanged -= h)
            .Where(x => x.EventArgs.PropertyName = "your_property_name");
    }
```